# Selenium verifying a scroll bar

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, scrollview

In a Java/Selenium test I am doing I need to verify the presence of a scroll bar (see highlighted yellow in image below).  From google searches all I get is a way to scroll using Javascript or something like *js.executescript("window.scrollBy(0,120)"*) or *action.sendKeys("Keys.DOWN")* but this does not really verify that the scroll bar is actually there.  I looked at the html but could not find any element for the scroll window.  There is a textarea element but no scrollbar.  It is possible somehow to tell from one of the values in the "class" attribute, or some other way to verify a scroll bar?

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code trials.